# Click event in ReactJS error: imports/ui/ParentComponent.jsx:5:16: Unexpected token (5:16)

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to learn Event in ReactJS. 
I created 2 components

ChildComponent is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

// App component - represents the whole app
export default class ChildComponent extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.onBannerClick}>Click me!</button>

    );
  }
}
```

And ParentComponent is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent.jsx'
// App component - represents the whole app
export default class ParentComponent extends Component {
  performMagic: function() {
    alert('TAADAH!');
  },
  render() {

    return (
      <BannerAd onBannerClick={this.performMagic} />

    );
  }
}
```

but I got the error

```
Errors prevented startup:

While building for web.browser:
imports/ui/ParentComponent.jsx:5:16: Unexpected token (5:16)

Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

I think the error is from

```
performMagic: function() {
    alert('TAADAH!');
  },
```

But I do know what the error is.
By the way, can anybody recommends me good debug tools for ReactJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using the ES6 syntax you'll have to bind the function to the instance using the following approach.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.performMagic = this.performMagic.bind(this)
}
```

This will allow you to use the *this* keyword in the onClick call

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent.jsx'
// App component - represents the whole app
export default class ParentComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.performMagic = this.performMagic.bind(this)
  }

  performMagic() {
    alert('TAADAH!');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BannerAd onBannerClick={this.performMagic} />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to write:

```
performMagic () {
  alert('TAADAH!');
},
```

You need to use new sintax for functions, when write class which is new sintax.

EDIT: You can use "React Developer Tools" chrome extension and gaearon "redux-devtools" for development.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the new ES6 syntax when making your React Component a class. Use

```
performMagic() {
 alert('TAADAH!');
}
```

make sure you don't put a comma after the function